# Est-ce que "blémissure" équivaut à "blémissement" ?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, néologismes, substantivation

Voici ce passage de "Récoltes et Semailles" :

> C'est un mystère, et s'il y a une "**foie**" en moi à ce sujet, elle ne consiste nullement en des "articles de foi" sur l'existence (ou la non existence) d'un au-delà et sur ses particularités, mais simplement en cette simple assurance : que les choses sont parfaites comme elles sont, y compris pour tout ce qui concerne la mort, et aussi pour tout ce qui concerne la naissance, toute aussi mystérieuse. Pendant longtemps, pourtant, j'avais exclu "le conflit" du nombre de ces choses - je le prenais comme une sorte de "bavure", une blémissure inadmissible, un "couac" tenace et saugrenu (voire révoltant) dans le concert de la Création.

Le mot "blémissure" dans la dernière phrase saute à l'œil. Je le comprends intuitivement comme "blémissement". Par contre, je voudrais savoir :

1. Est-ce que vous allez le comprendre de la même façon ? Et qu'est-ce que vous allez penser alors de ce choix de mots ?
2. Est-ce que c'est simplement une faute d'écriture à cause de la hâte ? Est-ce que vous le percevez comme faute ?
3. Est-ce que vous avez déjà rencontré ce néologisme - si c'en est un - dans un autre texte définitif et dans quel sens ?

**NB.** Je ne trouve pas ce mot dans les dictionnaires pour le moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Je ne suis pas vraiment sûr que l'on puisse, à notre époque, parler de néologisme tant on peut trouver ce mot dans:

Le Cotgrave (Début XVII) en tant que synonyme de blêmissement. (Sous l'orthographe *blesmisseure*, le verbe source s'orthographiant alors *blesmir*.)

Si on compare à un cas très semblable obtenu à partir de *MEURTRIR* pas non plus très éloigné sémantiquement parlant de blêmir, on notera une consécration inverse, *Meurtrissure* étant premier et *Meurtrissement* simple hapax, synonyme du premier.
Pareil pour *Blesser*, pas non plus éloigné dans le même champ sémantique, c'est *blessement* qui, pour garder encore sa place de vedette dans certains dictionnaires a néanmoins bien vieilli.

Ergo, en réponse précise à vos questions et par conséquent :

1/ OUI, + voir 3
2/ NON
3/ Il s'agit plus d'un archaïsme que d'un néologisme ou alors... s'agit-il d'un néologisme archaïsant...